# Github - giving credits for a file(s)

Tags: github

I currently have a PHP project which uses and contains [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), an open source file hosted on sourceforge.net.

How do I credit such in Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file seems to be licensed under the [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) (see its header lines) which is very permissive and has no copyleft.

IANAL, but as the license states you shall not remove the copyright notice in the according file you use.

If you want to be precise, add this "third party library/file" in a separate folder of your project and include the full MIT license within, too.

Besides that, a *kudos* to the developers/project page in your readme is always nice.